# Assets/scripts/Player.cs(40,36): error CS1519: Unexpected symbol `(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

Having some trouble in Unity with Scripting. Main problem is that I am trying to have my player walk and idel in my player script. the errors are: 
parsing errors
 and unexpected symbols

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed = 10f;
public Vector2 maxVelocity = new Vector2(3,5);
public bool standing;
public float jump = 15f;
public float airSpeedMultipler = .3f;
private Animator animator;

void start (){
    animator = GetComponent<Animator> ();
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    var forceX = 0f;
    var forceY = 0f;

    var absVelX = Mathf.Abs (GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.x);
    var absVelY = Mathf.Abs (GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.y);

    if (absVelY < .2f) {
        standing = true;
    } else {
        standing = false;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey ("right")) {

        if (absVelX < maxVelocity.x)

            forceX = standing ? speed : (speed * airSpeedMultipler);

        transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1, 1, 1);
    }
    animator.SetInteger("Animstate", 1);
} else {
    animator.SetInteger("Animstate",0);
        }

    } else if (Input.GetKey ("left")) {

        if (absVelX < maxVelocity.x)
            forceX = standing ? -speed : (-speed * airSpeedMultipler);

        transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey ("up")) {
        if (absVelY < maxVelocity.y)
            forceY = jump;
    }

    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2 (forceX, forceY));

}
}
```

Comment: Your curly braces '{' need to match 1-to-1. Proper indentation will go a long way for you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you close the block for `if (Input.GetKey ("right"))` before `animator.SetInteger("Animstate", 1);` and then you have your `else`, but at this point, there is no if active.